# How to animate the image in an reverse L shape

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

I am performing a task in such a way that I took one image and twenty to thirty  rectangular cell button.

For those rectangular cells I named them as 1,2,3,4,5,--------,30. I arranged the rectangular cells in an 6*7 matrix. Now if I click the rectangular cell button 29, the image has to find the shortest path in that matrix to reach that clicked button.

How do I perform this?

Comment: So they must move in straight lines?

Comment: yes they have to move in straight lines

Answer (score 1):

You have a single image that you want to animate to the location of one of 30 buttons? Further, you want it to move not in a diagonal, but first horizontally, then vertically? CodaFi's code is quite close to what I would do. I'd write an IBAction method that I would attach to all the buttons. Startig with CodaFi's code as a basis, here's the action method I'd suggest:

```
-(IBAction)animateImageToButton: (id) sender
{
  button = (UIButton *) sender;

  //First animate the image to the x position of the button
  CGPoint fPoint = CGPointMake(button.center.x, image.center.y);
  CGPoint sPoint = button.center;
  //animate x position first.
  [UIView animateWithDuration: 1.0f animations: ^
    {
      [image setCenter:fPoint];
    }
    completion ^(BOOL finished)
    {
      //Once that animation is complete, create 
      //a second animation to move to the button's y position
      [UIView animateWithDuration: 1.0f animations: ^
      {
        [image setCenter:sPoint];
      }];
    }];
}
```

That code would move a single UIImageView, called Image, onto the button that was tapped.

Answer (score 0):

I would not name the buttons but give them `tag`s. I would use the following scheme:

```
button.tag = xCoordinate *100 + yCoordinate;
```

So, for example, for the third button from the left in the top row the tag would be `301`. Retrieve the coordinates like this:

```
xCoordinate = button.tag / 100; 
yCoordinate = button.tag % 100;
```

Now all you have to do is animate the image to the `center` of the button or some other point near there by changing the x and y coordinates of the image's `frame`.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the tag approach that mundi's layed out, because the images would move in diagonal lines to reach their destination.  I imagine a for-loop would be appropriate, so here's my approach:

```
-(void)animateOnLinesWithClickedButton:(UIButton*)button {
    for (UIButton *image in self.view.subviews){
        CGPoint fPoint = CGPointMake(button.center.x, image.center.y);
        CGPoint sPoint = button.center;
        //animate x position first.
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
            [image setCenter:fPoint];
        }
             completion^(BOOL finished){
                   [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
                        [image setCenter:sPoint];
             }];
        }];
    }
}
```

This will animate your buttons one by one to the correct x, then y position.  Use the delay variation of this method to create a more realistic effect.

Comment: can you provide some sample application regarding this issue.Please am getting confused here